# Asp.net Web API Routing by action name fix

Tags: asp.net-mvc, rest, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-routing

I found this [article](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/web-api-routing-and-actions/routing-in-aspnet-web-api) at asp.net Learn website. I use this article to help me to create an API method to search in the database by email and not id.

However, if you take a look at the article, you will be able to help me fix my problem as follows:

my controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public string Details(string email);

[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Email")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetEmail(string email);
```

My WebApiConfig class

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "EmailApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { id = RouteParameter.Optional }
            );
```

First, The error I get for the Details method as follows:

> (Error    1   'MyApp.Controllers.UsersController.Details(string)' must
>   declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or
>   partial   D:\Abdulrhman A A\MyApp\Asp.net Web
>   API\Controllers\UsersController.cs    40  27  MyAppApplication)

Second, the error I get for the GetEmail method as follows:

> (Error    2   'MyApp.Controllers.UsersController.GetEmail(string)' must
>   declare a body because it is not marked abstract, extern, or
>   partial   D:\Abdulrhman A A\MyApp\Asp.net Web
>   API\Controllers\UsersController.cs    44  43  MyAppApplication)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The article provides a sample on how to configure routing. These last two samples are just for illustrative purposes, it is more like pseudo-code, not a working code. If you are just starting with C# these last code samples are confusing.

The errors that you are getting clearly describe what is going on - you need a method body. To fix it, instead of adding `;` at the end add `{}` and actually implement the method:

```
[HttpGet]
public string Details(string email)
{
    // Implement your method, so it returns string
}

[HttpGet]
[ActionName("Email")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetEmail(string email)
{
    // Implement your method so it returns HttpResponseMessage 
}
```

Comment: Good news, you confirmed my suggestion. I am now working on how to form the method body in case I am searching by email and not id. But I am still struggling in that, can you edit your post with method body please for email search inside the same table?

Comment: @AbuTaha It is totally unrelated to your initial question. Instead of asking follow up question in comments (where no one will probably see it), better ask a new question, clearly describing what you want to achieve and what is not working. See the [guidelines on how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: thank you @dotnetom . I am going to post another question.